# How do I create a working Sublime Text 3 plugin alias?

Tags: macos, plugins, alias, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm developing a plugin for ST3 in OSX 10.7.5. How can I keep the repo in an external directory and create an alias to that repo inside Sublime's `Packages` directory so that it works? I've tried creating an alias but the plugin commands do nothing unless the repo itself is in the Packages dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I develop a theme and I create a symlink to do so:

```
ln -s ~/path/to/foldername ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/foldername
```